# Is it possible to recognise and prevent MitM attacks on devices which use self-signed SSL certs?

Tags: tls, network, attacks, attack-prevention, man-in-the-middle

I use both Linux and Windows at work on a large enterprise LAN. The majority of the network configuration is out of my reach.

Certain SaaS applications that are hosted locally on the enterprise LAN, use self-signed SSL certificates. I am required to log into these on a regular basis.

Is there any sure way of knowing that the servers I'm logging into are the legitimate ones other than the obvious change of identity, supposing that it's possible a fellow employee might attempt a MitM attack?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The point of the server certificate is so that the client can make sure that it knows the correct, genuine public key for the server. Certificates signed by a CA are one way to achieve that (with the unspoken assumption that we trust the CA for signing only certificates with correct information in it, and not goofing it up). A self-signed certificate cannot convey such a guarantee.

However, in some cases, you can replace the certificate model with **direct trust**. Namely, you inform your Web browser that for a given, specific certificate can be trusted. Firefox describes that as a "security exception". This does not completely solves the issue, but at least it reduces it to the problem of making sure *once* that you are seeing the correct server certificate. Afterwards, your browser will remember that "exception" and won't bug you with scary warnings -- but it *will* glower like a drunk christmas tree if somebody tries to feed you another, distinct self-signed certificate.

For the initial registration, when you connect the first time to the server, have your browser display the "SHA-1 fingerprint" or "thumbprint". How it is named changes with the browser, but this is a SHA-1 hash value computed over the complete certificate, and expressed as 40 hexadecimal characters. Then, phone the sysadmin of the intended server and have him spell out the thumbprint of *his* certificate: if they match, then you know that your browser is seeing the right certificate, and can register it as a locally known security exception.

(The process described above is exactly what is done for [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell), and it works for SSL too.)

How to install a "security exception" depends on the browser and the operating system, and I am way too lazy to lookup and describe all the possible combinations. But, at least, you have the concept.

Comment: Thanks for the background theory and explanation. Not sure how feasible it is for me to contact every webmaster and DBA to verify this but I understand the point you are trying to make. Hopefully the fingerprint(s) don't change too often.

Comment: @synack Unless wishing to make a point to the powers that be, I can imagine contacting the webmasters to ask for certificate verification being unpopular, particularly if other end users start doing the same too. While it may not achieve anything, *formally* contacting relevant persons in the organisation to raise your concerns about the security implications and end user time wasted due to using self signed certificates rather than those from a trusted CA would be wise.

Comment: @synack - If you cannot go to this effort then do not trust self-signed certs.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not a question of effort, it's a limitation of feasibility. I utilize many systems in disparate locations. My working day shift is not usually the same as admins in different time zones.